How to sort the output of meta / slash commands in `psql`?
For example, how to sort the output below by the values in "Column" in the psql shell itself?
my_db=> \d auth_user
                                        Table "public.auth_user"
    Column    |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                Default                
--------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------
 id           | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('auth_user_id_seq'::regclass)
 is_superuser | boolean                  |           | not null | 
 username     | character varying(150)   |           | not null | 
 first_name   | character varying(150)   |           |          | 
 last_name    | character varying(150)   |           | not null | 
 email        | character varying(254)   |           |          | 
 is_staff     | boolean                  |           | not null | false
 is_active    | boolean                  |           | not null | false
 password     | character varying(128)   |           |          | 
 last_login   | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 date_joined  | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "auth_user_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "auth_user_username_6821ab7c_like" btree (username varchar_pattern_ops)
    "auth_user_username_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (username)

I know that this would be easy to do outside the psql shell, for example in Bash,
$ psql -U postgres -h localhost -d my_db -c '\d auth_user' | grep '^.*|' | sort -t'|' -k1

    Column    |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                Default                
 date_joined  | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 email        | character varying(254)   |           |          | 
 first_name   | character varying(150)   |           |          | 
 id           | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('auth_user_id_seq'::regclass)
 is_active    | boolean                  |           | not null | false
 is_staff     | boolean                  |           | not null | false
 is_superuser | boolean                  |           | not null | 
 last_login   | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 last_name    | character varying(150)   |           | not null | 
 password     | character varying(128)   |           |          | 
 username     | character varying(150)   |           | not null | 

but I'm curious if this could be done in psql at all.

I accepted @JaschaBeste's answer because it is the simplest one, and changing it to SELECT column_name FROM ... gives exactly what I needed. I wish I could accept @LaurenzAlbe's answer too, because I completely missed -E (same as \set ECHO_HIDDEN on in the psql shell) where the output is a gold mine to get deeper into PostgreSQL internals. Thank you all!

I am not aware of a way to do this for the slash commands itself but they use the exact data that is available in the information_schema.
So for \d you can query information_schema.columns table with typical sql and then use order by.
So in your case like this:
select 
  * 
from 
  information_schema.columns  
where 
  table_name = 'auth_user' 
order by 
  column_name;


You cannot change the sorting order of a psql meta-command, but you can figure out the metadata query behind the output:
psql -E -d my_db
my_db=> \d auth_user

That will also show you the metadata query. Copy and paste that query and add your own ORDER BY clause.
